# Easiest way to iterate

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this,

```
const data = [{
  prop1: 342141234213,
  prop2: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }
}]
```

Want the result,

```
[
{x: [{a: 342141234213, b: 1}]},
{y: [{a: 342141234213, b: 2}]},
{z: [{a: 342141234213, b: 3}]}
]
```

Is there a way to do this with one loop?  Tried many ways, but always end up with complicated stuff.  ES6/7 ok.  Assuming data can have more than one member.

Comment: By O(n2) you meant O(N^2), quadratic? I'm really curious how you achieved that? Linear solution is obvious, just map over `prop2`

Comment: Yes, but don't you have to iterate over data & inside iterate over prop2.  Assuming data has more than one member.

Comment: Yes, but still linear, O(N*M) where N is length of data and M is avg size of prop2

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you .  But not possible with one loop right?

Comment: @z.a. if you have 2 dimensions (`data` array and `prop2`'s properties) you can't access each element using only one loop. But it shouldn't be that complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Object.keys()` and `map()` the following way:

```js
const data = [{
  prop1: 342141234213,
  prop2: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }
}]

const res = data.map(e => {
  return Object.keys(e.prop2).map((d) => {
    return {[d]: [{a: e.prop1, b: e.prop2[d]}]};
  });
});

console.log(res);
```